# Return Response as string

Tags: c#, api, restsharp

I am trying to return a String response from a POST request using RestSharp.

This is what I'm trying

```
public IRestResponse PostNewLocation(string Name, string Type, Nullable<Guid> ParentId, string Location)
{
    object tmp = new
    {
        name = Name,
        type = Type,
        parentId = ParentId,
        Location = Location
    };
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tmp);

    var Client = new RestClient();
    Client.BaseUrl = new Uri(BaseURL);
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.Resource = string.Format("/Sample/URL?");
    request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
    IRestResponse response = Client.Execute(request);

    Console.Write(response.Content);

    if (!IsReturnedStatusCodeOK(response))
    {
        throw new HttpRequestException("Request issue -> HTTP code:" + response.StatusCode);
    }

    return response.Content;
}
```

I am getting the following error

> Error  CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'RestSharp.IRestResponse'

on this line

```
return response.Content;
```

How can I return a `string` response from RestSharp?

The response is a GUID String.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either change the return type of `PostNewLocation` to `string` if you want to return raw content of the response as a string:

```
public string PostNewLocation (
   ...
   return response.Content;
}
```

Or return `response` instead of `response.Content` if you want to return instance of `IRestResponse` (you can later get a raw content):

```
public IRestResponse PostNewLocation (
   ...
   return response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was a bit confused, I am getting the raw content later in the test, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your method is returning type IRestResponse.

Youre trying to return CONTENT, which is a string:

[image]

Comment: Please don't copy-past irrelevant code from RestSharp website - you can put a link to this documentation if you want to.

Comment: What was irrelevant about it? Any time someone posts a link to an article a mod pops in here and tells them to prefer putting content directly into the site over post links, which may go dead.

Comment: Yes link-only answers are not welcomed here as well. Link can expire, thus you should post a solution to the question as an answer and provide a links for further exploration of topic by op. No need to rage downvoting. Merry xmas

Comment: Merry xmas, you still havent said what was irrelevant about it.

Comment: Well, code from RestSharp had information about adding headers, parameters, execution requests, which does not solve the problem of op. You had `The response content is a property on the response object. You'll likely want to return that.` which is correct, but it's what op already has - he is returning `response.Content` and facing a problem. I would say that first thing to focus on is explaining where the problem is (type mismatch here) and how to solve it, with some sample code in a perfect world. Actually that is why I wasn't posting an answer waiting for your updates

Comment: Understood, you're right I missed the type mismatch part at first. I disagree that a full example from the library's webpage is irrelevant.